# Are 10,000 lines of code in a file "too much"?

Tags: coding-style, clean-code

I am a junior iOS developer and here at work I find huge files with sometimes over 10,000 lines of code. Is it a good practice to put this many lines in a single file? Or is it too much. Is there any rule of thumb which defines the length of file or better readability of code.

Comment: This depends to some degree on the tooling. Some IDEs allow to navigate inside a large code file very efficiently as long as the logical structure of the code is ok. But beware, even if your IDE can handle this for you, working with version control works usually better when the code files are not too large. Large files may cause more effort for diff and merge operations.

Comment: It depends on who you ask. For example, the research team around Alan Kay believes that 1) the ultimate documentation of a computing system is its source code, 2) a computing system should not require more than a college textbook's worth of documentation (~20,000 lines), and thus a personal computing system should not require more than 20,000 lines of code. The original Smalltalk system, which included kernel, device drivers, networking stack, graphics drivers, OS, virtual machine, interpreter, compiler, IDE, debugger, a graphical desktop, collaborative document editing, and much more, was

Comment: 60,000 lines of code in the 1970s. Alan Kay argued that 50 years later, with all the improvements in programming language design since the 1970s, it should be possible to do this in 20,000 lines. I believe they were down to about 30,000 lines of code when they ran out of funding. So, if you were to ask Alan Kay, 10,000 is not just too much code for a single file, but too much code for *the entire system*. On the other hand, Microsoft seems to be perfectly fine with about 50 *million* lines of code for Windows and 250 million for Office.

Comment: It depends on the language. In Python, for example, I start to question the size of a file if it's more than 100 lines.

Answer (score 9):

It depends. It mostly depends on the complexity.

If a method does simple thing A, followed by simple thing B, followed by simple thing C and so on and so on, lots of lines of code in a file are not a problem. At least not a problem that can be fixed by splitting a file into many small sub files.

Now if you have this and there are many, many lines of code, I’d look for code duplication. Someone might use 20 lines of code that could be handled by one helper method and one call, and if they did that 500 times then you can reduce this from 10,000 lines to 20 + 500 lines. That’s much much better than splitting the 10,000 line file into 10.

Your files may be large because someone put ten unrelated things into one file. That’s a case where you should split it. But splitting bigfile.cpp into into bigfilepart1.cpp to bigfilepart10.cpp doesn’t actually help.

Biggest files I had were a dozen files that contained each a TrueType font, converted to a static array of unsigned char. Each 20,000 to 80,000 lines - no problem because nobody ever looked at them.

That said, 10,000 lines of code is a lot in one file. Even people who don’t care about number of lines of code at all rarely have more than 2,000 to 3,000.

I’d say first find out what these ten thousand lines do. If you can reduce the number of lines significantly, excellent. If they are unrelated pieces, create files with related pieces. But first (walks over to workplace.stackexchange) don’t step on anyone’s toes. The developer you accuse of creating files that are too big might have very good reasons, for example “we got this code from a third party and have to merge updates from time to time”, or “my idiot manager thinks code in large files runs faster and I can’t change this until he retires next year”. Or you might be right, but he had more power and will hold a grudge.

Answer (score 3):

For rule-of-thumb, I would take two considerations (hypothetical questions) to begin with:

- What's your first 'gut' reaction when you open or view the file, does it feel manageable to you?
- How do the other developers you work with feel about it, particularly others who are relatively new to the project?

Excessive size for something is often seen as potential [Code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) ([Also see here](https://refactoring.guru/refactoring/smells)); indeed with so many lines in one file, it's very likely there are other Code smells contained within.

Rather than looking for rules-of-thumb, it's usually more constructive to introduce tooling with Code smell detection into your process such as [SonarQube](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/concepts/) to help you objectively measure the overall quality of your code.   (Or at least to try it 'offline' in a local development environment first)

It's typically much easier to take the output of a tool such as this to your co-workers and those who are ultimately responsible for code quality than it is to talk to those people about gut-feel and personal opinion because that takes most of the subjectivity out of the conversation and likely starts you with findings based on some carefully-tuned guidelines built by people who have spent years thinking about the most effective ways to analyse code quality.

Even if a tool does not explicitly check the size of a file, there are other things it will check which might lead you to conclude that the content of the file should be split up and refactored.

Answer (score 1):

> Are 10,000 lines of code in a file "too much"?

#### It is a matter of opinion, of habits, and of community.

For example, the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler has (in 2022) several big files. Its `gcc/gimplify.c` file has 16574 lines, measured by `wc -l` utility. You can view some variant of it [here](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/gcc/gimplify.c.html). In [GCC 11.1](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-11/) (april 2021) that file has 15697 lines.

The [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/) compiler has (in jan. 2022) no hand-written file bigger than 5931 lines: its file `typing/typecore.ml`. Splitting that file into smaller ones would take a lot of work. But Ocaml is distributed with a [Menhir](http://gallium.inria.fr/%7Efpottier/menhir/) *generated* source file `boot/menhir/parser.ml` of 48057 lines.

Most of the routines there are rather small.

A lot of routines are needed, or contain large `switch` statements, to handle every case of the internal representations ([GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html#GIMPLE)) of GCC.

In C or C++, a big file is compiled faster than several equivalent smaller files (because the  `#include` -ed header files are included and processed once). Refactoring it in smaller files is possible, but takes (human development) time and could increase compilation time of the entire project and in some cases could slightly increase the runtime (or force very costly compiler optimizations).

And the [SWIG](http://swig.org/) tool (version 4.0) has a file `Source/CParse/parser.c` of 13003 lines. But that file is [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) generated.

A good source editor (like [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)) is able to cope and to show large source files in 2022.

> Is there any rule of thumb which defines the length of file or better readability of code.

**Discuss that with your manager and colleagues.** The code you are writing today will be read (and improved) by them in 6 months.

My advice is to avoid having many statements (or lines of code) in a *single* method or function. I would recommend having less than a thousand lines of code in each of them (and usually, just a hundred or two). In the 1990 the recommendation (at some large software companies) might have been to avoid more than a hundred lines of code. In the [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) inference engine project (GPLv3+ licensed, on [github](https://github.com/RefPerSys/RefPerSys/)) we have every hand-written files having less than two thousand lines. We hope to generate (like [GCC MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/MELT-Starynkevitch-DSL2011.pdf) did) C files bigger than that.

Initialization routines (e.g. the one adding widgets in some GUI) tend to be large sequential routines.

Static analysis tools (like [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) or [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/)) for C or C++ are limited by the total size of the source code of a software project. The size of a given source file matters less. The size of each function and their total number matters more.

#### Readability is achieved by discussing, defining, following and documenting coding rules and [conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_conventions).

For example, [MISRA-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISRA_C) or [GNU coding standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html).

So in my opinion good comments matter more than file size.